# Unable to set min input hour and time to tomorrow 16h on <input type="datetime-local">

Tags: javascript, html

I am unable to set minimum date and time to a specific value when using:

I was able to set it on only date using below:

```
 <input type="date" id="datePickerId" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Pasirinkite pristatymo datą')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
```

JS

```
var today = new Date();
datePickerId.min = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate() + 1)).toISOString().split("T")[0];
```

But I can't make it work on type = datetime-local.

I was able to set the input to the required like so:

```
 <input type="datetime-local" id="inputDate" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Pasirinkite pristatymo datą')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
```

JS

```
 $("#inputDate").val(moment().add(1, 'days').hours(16).startOf('hour').format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss"));
```

But it isn't the minimum date and user can still choose any date prior to the minimum. Is there a way to set it to be the minimum value? I tried applying moment to today.setDate like in the example without hours but I can't seem to get it right.

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried setting the value of `min` to the string value of the date in ISO 8601 format?

Comment: Yes it helps! Thank you. However I can't seem to pass the min time. If I will try using it 
with the below logic:

$(document).ready(function(){
  elem = document.getElementById("dateInput")
  var today = new Date();
  var iso = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate() + 1)).toISOString();
  var minDate = iso.substring(0,iso.length-8);
  elem.value = minDate
  elem.min = minDate
It will not give the correct as it takes current date and time. 
Is there a way to set a static min time ( 16 h )

Comment: `iso.substring(0,iso.length-8)` Why `-8`? That would take off the time portion.

Comment: It took off only the milliseconds but left minutes and hours from the view of the input.
Hours and minutes themselves are my time zone -2 hours. But how do I set them to be 16h:00Min tomorrow. As today.getDate() + 1 getTime() "some milliseconds" will always take current time, instead of a static value.

Comment: `new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() + 1, 16, 0, 0, 0)` [The constructors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) are a good way of getting the results you want.